# eclipse plugins for remote system

Tags: eclipse, plugins

what is the plugin i would able to get from eclipse for "remote server system." I want to just open files from the remote server and continue my web project from a specific home folder.

I need to also able to have the input for mysql database so the eclipse would able to debug it as well.

Are there such plugins?
I have been looking for this for a long but I dont find any.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for the [Remote Systems Explorer](http://www.eclipse.org/tm/), which is part of the target management project in Eclipse.